# PHP echo'ing JavaScript will not work

Tags: javascript, php

I've been trying to use PHP to output some JavaScript in a reload image script, but I can't get it to work.

The original code is:

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    function reloadImage() { 
    var myDate = new Date();

    <?php 
        $len = count($_POST['custom_wall']);
        for ($x = 0; $x < $len; $x++) {
            $imgNum = $x + 1;
            $jstxt1 = 'img' . $imgNum . '.src = \'http://' . $resultExplode[0] . '/jpeg?t=\' + myDate.getTIme();' . PHP_EOL;
            echo $jstxt1;
        }
        echo '}' . PHP_EOL;

        echo 'if (document.getElementByID) {' . PHP_EOL;
        for ($y = 0; $y < $len; $y++) {
            $imgNum2 = $y + 1;
            $jstxt2 = 'var img' . $imgNum2 . ' = document.getElementByID(\'Cam' . $imgNum2 . '\');'  . PHP_EOL;
            echo $jstxt2;
        }

    ?>
window.setInterval('reloadImage()', 1000); 

}         
</script>
```

When I run the page, it renders the correct output (see below) but doesn't reload the images.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function reloadImage() {
var myDate = new Date();
img1.src = 'http://172.16.140.56/jpeg?t=' + myDate.getTIme();
img2.src = 'http://172.16.140.56/jpeg?t=' + myDate.getTIme();
img3.src = 'http://172.16.140.56/jpeg?t=' + myDate.getTIme();
}
if (document.getElementByID) {
var img1 = document.getElementByID('Cam1');
var img2 = document.getElementByID('Cam2');
var img3 = document.getElementByID('Cam3');
window.setInterval('reloadImage()' , 1000);
}
</script>
```

BUT, if I don't use PHP, and just insert the JS exactly as it is outputted, the script will work correctly.

I tried echoing the entire script in PHP, thinking that maybe the order it was interpreting was an issue, but no luck. I also wondered if it had to do with using the end-of-line function.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to load the js into a function and call an `onload` on the body tag?

Comment: Consider an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if` condition:

```
if (document.getElementByID) {
```

will always be false, because `document.getElementByID` is `undefined`. JS is case sensitive; change the `D` on the end to a lowercase `d`:

```
if (document.getElementById) {
```

Or just remove the `if` test entirely, because all browsers support `document.getElementById` so there's no need to test for it.

You will also need to make the same change to the lines inside the `if`.

(Finally, the script element would need to be included on the page somewhere after the elements it tries to manipulate - just before the closing `</body>` tag is a common place to put script elements.)

Comment: Of course it was a capitalization error. Le sigh. That was it, much obliged.